# k3s and kafka network -- port blocked for some reason

Tags: confluent-platform, k3s

I have the following setup for kafka running in a k3s environment.

The source for which can be found in [git](https://github.com/CraigGoodspeed/kafka-k8s).

Zookeeper starts up without a hitch and is happy.

However kafka the first replica starts fine, however it never gets to the second replica since the readinessProbe fails.

I can ping kafka by the FQDN name, `ping kafka-app-0.kafka-app.avc.svc.cluster.local`.

however `nc kafka-app-0.kafka-app.svc.cluster.local 9093` fails.

On the local minikube environment this works 100%.

I'd like to think I have tried all avenues to debug this but I keep hitting a brick wall, is there anything you could suggest to assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After slamming my head on the desk for about 2 days...

1. I have a sore head.
2. Reading documentation helps.

According to the documentation...

> **Iptables**
>
> If you are running iptables in nftables mode instead of legacy you
> might encounter issues. We recommend utilizing newer iptables (such as
> 1.6.1+) to avoid issues.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463181/k3s-networking-between-pods-not-working) SO post sorted the issue out for me